# How can I Filter Data in RethinkDB using C# Driver?

Tags: c#, .net, rethinkdb

Trying to use Filter to get emotion data from my rethinkdb but using the C# Driver
[The data i want to have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v9FRB.png)

Can't seem to find out how this works in the C# Driver

This is the command in the data explorer that i want to have for c#

r.db('sitadapt').table('FaceReaderData').filter({type: 'emotionData'})

Answer (score 0):

the solution is HashMap
'double result = R.Db("sitadapt").Table("FaceReaderData").Filter(R.HashMap("type","emotionData")'